# What is the best way for me to connect to a offline database through C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have an application that needs to store loads of data in a table format. I want something easy to configure, which is also in built with C#.NET. I don't want to have to include additional DLL files.

Also some links to tutorials, explaining the connection process and querying would be great. I'm assuming this is just like PHP, but which database type do I need?

It needs to be able to hold a lot of data and the ability to perform backups would be nice.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for not wanting to include additional DLLs?  That's a pretty restrictive requirement.

Comment: I want to keep it simple to start with

Comment: If simplicity is a top priority, you may want to have a look at WebMatrix.  It is extremely simple to get started working with data, and configuration is minimal: http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/web-development-101-part-5-using-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an offline database you could use [SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174038%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), as its a in-process database that does not require being attached to a server instance, which is really what you want then. Here is an example in C# on how you would connect, and populate a data table to manipulate some data.

```
// this connectionstring can also be an absolute file path
string connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.sdf";
using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString)) {
    try {
        connection.Open();
    } 
    catch (SqlCeException) {
        // connection failed
    }
    using (SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM <table>", connection)) {
        using (DataTable table = new DataTable("<table>")) {
            adapter.Fill(); // Populate the table with your select statement

            // do stuff with the datatable
            // example:
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) {
                row["mycolumn"] = "somedata";
            }

            table.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

You can even use commands instead of data tables

```
using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM <table> WHERE id = '0'", connection)) {
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // executes command
}
```

Comment: An alternative to SQL Server CE is the C# SQLite wrapper, available at http://goo.gl/D4Dnz. Among other things, it supports user-defined functions written in C# or other .NET languages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "built in with C#.NET", but SQL Server Express comes with Visual Studio.

If you're looking for "a self-contained, embeddable, zero-configuration SQL database engine", you could try [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ease of [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)

Not build-in but easily added, no install and free.